# Input lag in Textboxes inside a ListView

Tags: windows, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP app that has a view which is, sort of, like excel. The user can input data on text fields, which are inside a ListView. Upon scrolling, more items are added in the ListView and hence more textboxes come into play.

The problem that I am facing with this is that the typing on these textboxes has a lot of lag. I was using caliburn micro mvvm framework and thought it is slowing down the app (which it was, the navigation mostly) so I removed it but there is no effect on the typing lag.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Could you share sample to reproduce the issue that type on these textboxes has a lot of lag

Comment: Is your problem calling some code on text changing? That could cause your lag. Instead of calling when the user has finished typing something.

Comment: @visc Yes, it was. I had to change the logic to make the app work without the text changing event. Can you please guide on how to call the event after the user has stopped typing? Don't think there would be an event for this.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I was able to resolve the problem, thank you.

Comment: @Anss I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling code in TextChanging- this will fire every time a user enters or deletes a character from the TextBox. Not good. Unfortunately TextChanged will also do the same thing.

You want to fire your code when the user hits the enter key on KeyUp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keyup

```
private void myTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        // the user has pressed enter and is done entering text, do something here
    }
}
```